# Web Crawler not working in nested divs

Tags: python, web-crawler

[image]

I am trying to make a web crawler that picks the interest of the people. Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def facebook_spider():
    url = 'https://www.facebook.com/abhas.mittal7'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text , "html.parser")
    for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'mediaRowWrapper'}):
        print div.text

facebook_spider()
```

It is not showing any results. However if I type in a different class of div (the divs that are at the top of the page) then it shows the content. I think there is some problem with the nested divs but I have tried this code in sample html page with too many nested divs, it worked. Kindly help.

Comment: When I open Chrome Inspector for the above URL and search for 'mediaRowWrapper' there are no hits. This is why your code doesn't find the class. Is this the correct class?

Comment: check the update @lambo477

Comment: I think the issue is that I was signed in to Facebook

Comment: try it in incognito if you have chrome

Comment: Can't open this page to check if the `div` actually have text inside. But does `print div` or even `print div.prettify()` print something?

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger, no it doesn't print. I think it's some privacy issue

Comment: Well, the only way to be certain is to print the whole `soup` and compare it with the page displayed with and without credentials.

Comment: it is printing the whole source code

Comment: It could be the case that the portion of the page containing your div is generated after some user interactions with the browser, which could trigger a javascript function or ajax call. This would explain why your code is not finding it.

Comment: Okay! So can't it be crawled now?

Comment: I tried my same code on my twitter timeline, it works perfect, but not so for facebook. Any way we can crawl on facebook?

Comment: @narko can you try this and find some fault? I made an example.txt file of the source code. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312640/cannot-crawl-and-access-a-particular-div-in-the-text-file

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
import urlparse,urllib,codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/abhas.mittal7'
html=urllib.urlopen(url)
htmltext=html.read() 

def gettext(htmltext):
soup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()#removing styles and scripts

text = soup.get_text()
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

# return text.encode('utf-8') #or print it or whatever you see fit


gettext(htmltext)
```

Comment: Unable to implement your code in my code. Can you help by typing in how to integrate with my code?

Comment: not working. I think it's facebook's policy that we cannot crawl on their page. If i run the same code on another website, it works fine

Comment: no, everything that u can see, can be crawled. you just have to find the method for it. in my country facebook is censored so I can't help u any more.

Comment: can you try doing it taking any id? I just want the entries of favorites section every individual has on facebook

Comment: that would be easy,I'm not gonna write down your code but I can tell you where to go: you can traverse over the `htmltext`, find the "favorites" keyword, and then apply the `gettext()` function to get the text and output it line by line. remember, `regex` is your friend.

Comment: when i run your code, it displays only the name of the person whose link we give in the url

Comment: can you try this and find some fault? I made an example.txt file of the source code, but still it's not working. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312640/cannot-crawl-and-access-a-particular-div-in-the-text-file

Comment: really? thats so weird, i'm sry i can't test it for facebook, but everywhere else it works fine... from what you're saying I can only guess that the html source file is not loaded with one href, I know that facebook uses wrappers maybe they use it for the page too. my suggestion is that u store the "href" tags (before riping it off in script.extract(). and see if other parts of the page is loaded using links.