# Cannot crawl and access a particular div in the text file

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have the following code and I want to access the text of a particular div.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urlparse
example = open('example.txt')
html = example.read()



def gettext(htmltext):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "lxml")
    for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'_5pbx userContent'}):
        print div.text

gettext(html)
```

At first, I tried it through a link to a facebook profile but it didn't work. But now I copied the whole source code and saved it in example.txt file. Still, it cannot access the div with class `_5pbx usercontent`. You can download the source at

> view-source:https://www.facebook.com/abhas.mittal7?fref=ts

Please make an example.txt file and try running my code. I don't know what's the problem. Kindly help me out.

Comment: I am not seeing that "div" in the page source code... can you post the data you are trying to extract exactly?

Comment: Likewise: when I save the source code I don't see the class `_5pbx`. Can we see the exact data?

Comment: Scraping is not allowed according to the TOS: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Okay. But even when I make a text file of the source code, it is not working. Why would that happen?

Comment: @Joe: Please find the download link for the source code here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9q9YK3qNDvxeEhURk5DQkhjdjA/view?usp=sharing . Sorry I didn't know facebook doesn't show same profile to users in different countries.

Comment: @lambo477 : Find the source code above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Crawler not working in nested divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309945/web-crawler-not-working-in-nested-divs)